# Checking if string characters can be arranged to form another string

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, strings

I am working on a code project that checks if all the characters in `str1` can be arranged to form another string (`str2`).  If all the characters in `str2` are present in `str1` (including any repeated characters in `str2`, i.e. if `str2` has two 'a' characters, `str1` must correspondingly have two as well), then the function returns `true`.

For example, here are some test cases below and the intended return:

> ```
> str1 = 'rkqodlw'
> str2 = 'world'
> Expected: true
>
> str1 = 'cedewaraaossoqqyt'
> str2 = 'codewars'
> Expected: true
>
> str1 = 'katas'
> str2 = 'steak'
> Expected: false
>
> str1 = 'scriptjava'
> str2 = 'javascript'
> Expected: true
> ```

I have a working code solution, but I'd like to refactor for optimal performance as there are a quite a number of random tests (of unknown length) that the code must test against and my code isn't completing the tests in the recommended timeframe.

```js
function stringscrambling(str1, str2) {
  var arr1 = str1.split('');
  var arr2 = str2.split('');
  var index;
  var l = arr2.length;

  while (l--) {
    index = arr1.indexOf(arr2[l]);
    if (index > -1) {
      arr1.splice(index, 1);
    } else { 
    return false;
    };
  }
  return true;
}
```

I originally used a basic for loop (with the array length cached as a variable and not in the `for` statement) as follows:

```js
for (var i = 0, l = arr2.length; i < l ; i++) {
    index = arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]);
    if (index > -1) {
      arr1.splice(index, 1);
    } else { 
      return false;
    };
  }
  return true;
 }
```

but tried the `while`-loop in reverse as I [read](https://blogs.oracle.com/greimer/entry/best_way_to_code_a) that specific looping would offer a bit better in terms of benchmarked performance. The change in loop offered a negligible performance upgrade.

Are there any other specific tricks I can implement on my code that can speed it up and still retain the original functionality?

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve.  Do you think you could provide examples of strings that would and would not pass the test?

Comment: Hi Robert, the code passes the tests  (i'm privy to a handful of the test cases and they all consist of `str1` and `str2` strings of less than 60 lowercase alpha characters ONLY) but there is a 6000ms timeout and apparently my code is not completing all the tests in the specified timeframe.

Comment: This lacks an example like "abcd", "abracadabra", false.

Comment: I believe the term is 'anagram'.

Comment: Would you mind testing and posting performance comparisons of the various algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another hash-based algorithm. It compiles the target string (str2) into a hash of characters and counts, then it iterates through the characters in the source string (str1) and decrements the counts in the hash (decompiles). If all of the character counts from the target are consumed, it is a match.

```
function stringscrambling(target, source) {
  var ntarget = target.length, nsource = source.length;
  if (ntarget <= nsource) {
    // compile the target
    var charhash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < ntarget; ++i) {
      var c = target[i];
      charhash[c] = (charhash[c] || 0) + 1;
    }

    // decompile the target
    for (var i = 0; i < nsource && ntarget > 0; ++i) {
      var c = source[i];
      if (charhash[c]) {
        --charhash[c];
        --ntarget;
      }
    }
  }
  return ntarget == 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle to show it works: https://jsfiddle.net/zwotntg5/

This approach assumes that the performance of accessing characters in a string by index and accessing properties in an object/hash is better than array-based operations.

Comment: why `"thestring", "grenastrictichal"` equals `true`?

Comment: Because all of the characters in "thestring" can be found in "grenastrictichal". It's the same as the "codewars"-in-"cedewaraaossoqqyt" case in the original question.

Comment: the original question does not included some examples. ty.

Answer (score 7):

The way to improve your performance is to use a better algorithm, specifically, sort both strings and compare:

```
function stringscrambling(str1, str2) {
 var sort1 = str1.split('').sort().join('');
 var sort2 = str2.split('').sort().join('');

 return sort1 === sort2;
}
```

Comment: Hi Amit!  Thanks for the help, however I realized that this might not work for my needs (i.e. str1 may be of larger length than str2, so a strict sort and compare between strings wouldn't return properly for all test cases).   I added some test cases above that hopefully sheds more light on what's the requirement for the code.

Comment: While sorting and comparing isn't quite enough, it's almost there: walk both sort results checking whether for equality. Skip "1" when smaller, return false if end on 1 or greater, true when end on 2. (You may consider the approaches establishing char -> count an application of counting sort.)

Comment: @greybeard - That will work, and would probably be ideal provided the input was fairly short.  Sorting takes longer than using a map as in James' solution, so I'd prefer that if the input could get long...

Answer (score 7):

It might be useful to create an object which contains each character and their count in the string.

e.g.

```
var str1 = "Foobar";
var str2 = "Foobarbaz";

var str1Count = {
  "F": 1,
  "o": 2,
  "b": 1,
  "a": 1,
  "r": 1
}

var str2Count = {
  "F": 1,
  "o": 2,
  "b": 2,
  "a": 2,
  "r": 1,
  "z": 1
}
```

And then compare the counts to see if one string can compose another.

Consideration: I am assuming there could be 'extra' characters in one of the strings. If each string is equal length and we're just trying to see if we can rearrange one into another, the above suggestion about sorting should work just fine.

To create the suggested object, you could do this:

```
var letterCount = function(str){
  var letterCount = {};

  str.split('').forEach(function(char){
    letterCount[char] = letterCount[char] === undefined ? 1 : letterCount[char] + 1;
  });

  return letterCount;
}
```

Comment: I'd go for this solution because it's an O(n) time-complexity algorithm.  Run through each string once and count letters, then run through each count and compare.  The sorting method may be easier, but it runs in O(n log n), so will take noticeably longer as your input size increases.  Of course there's a trade-off in that this adds space complexity instead, but if you limit the input to just the standard ASCII range, it's not all that much memory.

Comment: Reminds me of [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).